# What are w0 and w1 respectively after training with the following two examples of (x, y) in the given order?

Tags: gradient-descent, linear-regression

[image]
The answer is supposed to be w0 = 2.8229, w1 = 2.4686. I'm not sure how that is the case.

Can you please also show how you arrived at the solution?

Comment: $w_i = w_i - \alpha \nabla MSE$, apply it with the different points updating the weights

Comment: How do you calculate the gradient for each weight each time? Can you please explain?

Comment: @LuminousStar It's written in your post, no? Otherwise, the gradient is just the vector of partial derivatives. If you don't know what a derivative is, then this question is quite difficult. A partial derivative is just a derivative where you consider other variables (in this case, weights) to be constants.